# Objects, substances or entities that compel or discern truth in traditional mythological canons?

Tags: myth-identification

In modern mythologies I'm noticing increasing reference to objects/substances that can tell or discern truth.  Most famously, the use of [truth serum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_thiopental#Truth_serum) as a trope in the spy genre in particular, and [Wonder Woman](http://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-rebirth-origin/)'s miraculous golden cord, newly rebranded as the [Lariat of Hestia](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2017/06/wonder-woman-heroine-of-the-post-truth-age/528780/).  The [alethiometer](http://hdm.wikia.com/wiki/Alethiometer) (aka the [golden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#History) compass) from Phillip Pullman's heavily mythological [His Dark Materials](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70959/his-dark-materials-mythology-and-symbolism-behind-d%C3%A6mon-forms) is a more recent example.

**Are there canonical precedents for this power of truth?**

Pullman's alethiometer is clearly an oracle, but it is also a device, almost certainly modeled partly on the [antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism), so it can be understood as distinct from a oracular entity in that the possessor controls the device.

Comment: Fragarach is a sword from Celtic mythology, according to the Wikipedia page no one can move our lie with the sword at their throat.

Comment: I'll upvote if you formally post an answer. The idea that [Fragarach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragarach) could "cut through any shield or wall, and had a piercing wound from which no man could recover" are pretty good metaphors for truth imo. [Wikipedia page needs a citation, but we could probably run that down in a separate question.]

Answer (score 4):

***[Ma'at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maat)*** is the ancient Egyptian goddess of Truth, and is represented by a feather in the ancient [Egyptian Book of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Dead). The feather determines the truthfulness of the deceased.

The deceased is brought before [Osiris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris) and recites ritual declarations of his purity. But judgement is not rendered until the deceased's heart is weighed against the feather of Ma'at. If the heart and feather balance, then the deceased has been truthful and goes on to eternal life. If not, the Devourer [Ammit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammit) takes him.

This jpeg from Wikipedia shows a scene, similar to a multi-panel comic strip from the sarcophagus of one [Hunefer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunefer), a scribe who lived during the 19th Dynasty, about 1300 BCE.

In the middle panel, Hunefer's heart (on the left side of the scale) is being weighed against the feather (on the right side) with Osiris presiding and [Anubis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis) and Ammit looking on. On the right, Horus presents Hunefer (who has passed the test) to Osiris.

[image: BD_Hunefer]
<sup>Jpeg source: [Wikipedia: File:BD_Hunefer.jpg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BD_Hunefer.jpg), Original on display in the [British Museum](https://www.britishmuseum.org/)</sup>